Make tunnel moving with path constraint move around camera
I Want to move a (warp)tunnel made with a bezier circle around a camera, so it looks like the camera is moving, but actually the tunnnel is moving. Im trying to create this animated tunnel to later use in a game. The tunnel is rigged with a bone to the stationary part. I tried to animate it manually with keyframes, but that made it very bumpy, as seen in the video below. It does give an indication of what i want to create though.

I tried to make the bone follow the bezier circle that made the shape of the tunnel, but that just gave this weird result in the second video, where the tunnel doesnt move so that the stationary part is still in the tunnel. Does anyone know what I should do to get a result like the first video, but with follow path bone constraint?



You have a camera and a tunnel... is there any specific reason why you are doing this with an armature? And is there a specific reason why the tunnel has to move around the camera instead of moving the camera through the tunnel?

As Gordon says I would make the camera follow a curve that follows the tunnel shape

The reason is because I am planning on exporting this animation to use in a game, where there isnt a camera to be moved, just the tunnel

I've got some sort of answer here .. but it's not 'pure' .. (I can't justify it mathematically )
